# How to sort a multimensional array by a value alphabetically in PHP

Tags: php, sorting

I need to sort an array alphabetically depending of the value of lat_name. I tried the SORT function but it had no effect.

```
    array(20) {
  [126]=>
  array(5) {
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(8) "Marlène"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(7) "GAL"

  }
  [4]=>
  array(5) {
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(6) "Agnès"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(5) "MIO"

  }
  [7]=>
  array(5) {
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(5) "Alain"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(7) "PLAT"

  }
  [5]=>
  array(5) {
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(5) "Alain"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(8) "DIÈS"

  }
  [9]=>
  array(5) {
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(9) "Alexandre"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(8) "MIGNE"

  }
```

Comment: What language are you asking about?

Comment: oupss sorry PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

c.f. [uksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php)

You write a custom function that defines your comparisons and the sorter uses that.

Comment: For useful extension discussions, look up the Schwartzian Transform and the Orcish Maneuver as commonly used in Perl. The designs work fine in other languages with this sort of callout.